# Getting error while installing parcel bundler in my node.js application in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, express, npm, parceljs

Getting error while installing parcel-bundler using npm, my command is follows:
**npm install -g parcel-bundler**

Below is error description.

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Fzsf0KuydGYbbeMJ+WVIy'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\warrior\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-12T05_01_07_407Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Try first cleaning the cache:

npm clean-install